# How to stop ImageView from overlapping elements below it after programmatically setting the image?

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I have the following elements defined in the XML layout

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:fillViewport="true">

   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
      android:visibility="visible">

        <!--some more elements up here that I left out -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/assetImageTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/asset_photo_header"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uploadRemarksEditText" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/assetImageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/barcodeImageTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/asset_barcode_photo_header"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/assetImageView" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/assetBarcodeImageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barcodeImageTextView" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The desired structure would be to have:

---

**Asset photo header**

*Asset photo ImageView*

**Barcode photo header**

*Barcode photo ImageView*

---

Now, when the layout is first inflated, everything looks OK. When the asset ImageView's image is set, it will obviously expand the ImageView height -- however, in doing so it seems to overlap (and hides) the rest of the elements that are supposed to be below it.

I've included screenshots below for demonstration:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE1xC.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuWZX.jpg)

Things I have tried:

1. Calling `imageView.getParent().requestLayout();`
2. Calling `imageView.requestLayout();`
3. Calling `barcodeImageTextView.requestLayout();`

Would appreciate any ideas from you.

---

It turns out it may have been a bug with ConstraintLayout, I stumbled upon this answer for a different question which suggested using the beta version.

`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5'`

The problem is now resolved!

Comment: use a LinearLayout instead of the ConstraintLayout and set the LinearLayout orientation to vertical. :)

Comment: Thanks Droi, that would probably would have worked as it turned out the issue was with ConstraintLayout -- most likely a bug as this behaviour is corrected once I changed to the beta implementation using this line:     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5'

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it may have been a bug with *ConstraintLayout*, I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48198357/9402851) for a different question which suggested using the beta version.

The problem is now resolved!